# Helping users remember their activities

Tags: activity-feed

I have a web based system, where users can work with each other.

Now there are two requirements:

- Helping each user to remember what she was doing the last time she logged on, to ease their warm-up when logging on again.
- Showing users what other users have been doing to give them an impression what the others are up to.

What are good methods to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

An activity log is a common way to achieve this.

You have such a log on this site:

[image: The activity log on this site]

Or something like this:

[image: An activity log on the Movable Type system]

You can obviously offer filter such as:

- My activity
- Search by user
- All activity
- Etc.

Comment: how do I know what are interesting activities and how much of them should I keep? The last 100? The last 2 Months?